# Don't understand this behaviour: changing the value that a pointer points to causes the pointer value itself to change in C?

Tags: c, pointers

My goal is to write a canary-like mechanism to detect overflow in a character buffer. What I'm trying to do is to get the address of the end of the buffer and place a canary there, so that writing past the buffer would cause the canary value to change. After some debugging, I found that a problem is when I write a value to the address, the value of the address itself changes unexpectedly. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int secret = rand();
  char buf[8];
  char *aft_buf = buf + 8;
  printf("aft buf address = %p\n", aft_buf);
  int *canary = (int *) aft_buf;
  *canary = secret;
  printf("canary address = %p\n", canary); // this value becomes different from aft_buf. why?
  
  return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with `gcc -fno-stack-protector`, and I don't get this problem when I compile with `-O2` flag.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior. `aft_buf` holds the one-past address after `buf`, and is not legally dereferencable. Casting that to an `int *` (or anything , for that matter), and deref-writing an `int` value is clear UB.

Comment: Your program has a buffer overflow and undefined behaviour.

Comment: `*canary = secret;` Where do you think, you are writing here? What makes you think you might be allowed to do that? If you do things you are not allowed to, you must take the consequences.

Comment: I see, I didn't know it was undefined, thanks! Does this mean I need to increase the size of the buffer? Or is there other correct ways to write an int to a specific address in memory?

Comment: Well isn't the whole point of this to compile _without_ `-fno-stack-protector` to have the compiler handle the canary?

Comment: @Lundin yes definitely! this code is not for production, only for learning purposes and to understand how canary-like mechanism work

Comment: Why do you think you can write an int (4-byte value) to an unaligned location? On some architectures this will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have space for the canary:

```
char buf[8+sizeof(int)];
```